# Fungus or a boring beetle?

Tags: fungus

[image]

No idea what is causing this but it has been very rapid!   I suspect a boring beetle infestation of some sort but how to treat?

Comment: Hi Lindsay, you can help us by editing your question to add your location and if you know what kind of tree it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is larva eating the live layer of bark ( cambrium ?). Not fungus. Borers go into the wood and generally leave only a small hole in the bark.